# How to route traffic through different interfaces based on the port number?

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, socks, iproute2

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i usb0 -t mangle -p tcp --dport 8080 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

// route the traffic with mark 1 to myusb0 table

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table myusb0
```

ip route ls

```
192.168.0.0/24 dev usb1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.136  metric 1 
192.168.3.0/24 dev usb0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.182  metric 1
```

ip rule ls

```
0:  from all lookup local 
32762:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup myusb0 
32763:  from 192.168.3.0/24 lookup myusb0 
32764:  from 192.168.0.1/24 lookup myusb1 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

ip route ls table myusb0

```
default via 192.168.3.2 dev usb0
```

ip route ls table myusb1

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev usb1
```

// open up socks on port 8080

```
ssh -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:8080 root@192.168.3.182
```

// check if it works

curl --socks5 192.168.3.182:8080 ip.appspot.com

```
channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
curl: (7) Failed to receive SOCKS5 connect request ack.
```

I have two Internet connections from two different ISPs and I would like to open up a proxy/socks5 on each one.  I thought it would make sense to associate each interface with a port number so that we can manage the connections.

I've created two routing tables (`myusb0` and `myusb1`) for each device (`usb1` and `usb0`), then marked the traffic based on the port number (e.g. on port `8080` I mark it 1) and route the traffic on that mark to the specific table (`myusb0`). Then I tried to open a socks5 on that IP and tried it locally but for some reasons it doesn't work.

Once I get it working locally I think I should open up the socks in a reverse manner so that I can make it available to the remote server(s) that need to use it.

Any idea why it's not currently working and how I should fix it? For some reasons I think the socks connection is trying the default gateway from the main table which is not set instead to follow the port `8080` mark rule and try the myusb0 table. I'm using Ubuntu (latest version).

Should be mentioned that both ISPs provide dynamic IPs

**Edit**

As I suspected it seems that the traffic to port 8080  is not being routed  (nevermind the socks issue) but I don't know why

```
 curl portquiz.net:8080 
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, when you do:

```
$ ssh -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:8080 root@192.168.3.182
$ curl --socks5 192.168.3.182:8080 ip.appspot.com
```

The following events occur:

1. CURL opens a TCP connection from *[YOUR-HOST]:[RANDOM-PORT]* to the SOCKS server that SSHD runs on *192.168.3.182:8080*
2. SSHD accepts the connection
3. CURL asks SSHD to open a new connection from *192.168.3.182:[RANDOM-PORT]* to *ip.appspot.com:80*
4. SSHD tries to open a TCP connection and fails
5. SSHD returns a failure message: *"channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed"*

SSHD can't open a new connection because IP packets destinated to *ip.appspot.com:80* are being generated in the router box - not being routed through it. Because of that, packets don't receive the mark, kernel skips both *myusb0* and *myusb1* tables and the absence of a matching route entry in *main* table causes a *network unreachable* error. If you wanted to manage locally-generated packets, the right chain under *mangle* table would be *OUTPUT* instead of *PREROUTING*.

About the port test problem:

```
$ curl portquiz.net:8080 
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Please, check router configuration:

1. Is there a default gateway in the "main" table?

   ```
   $ ip route show
   ```
2. Is packet forwarding enabled?

   ```
   $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
3. Are packets being NATed?

   ```
   $ iptables -t nat -nvL
   # iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o myusb0 -j MASQUERADE
   # iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o myusb1 -j MASQUERADE
   ```